# how to bypass forward declarations

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, forward-declaration

this program works, but how do i make this program work without the forward declarations in UList.H. it gives me errors if i remove them. if u want to see these errors check my other question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23278943/how-to-implement-sort-functions-using-vectors.

**UList.h**

```
#ifndef PROJ_ULIST_H
#define PROJ_ULIST_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//forward declarations of UList and friended functions
template<class T> class UList;

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const UList<T>&);

template<class T>
void sort(UList<T>&);

template <class T>
class UList{
public:
    UList(size_t=10);
    void insert(const T&);
    bool erase(const T&);
    bool find(const T&);
    size_t size() const;
    bool empty() const;
    friend void sort<T>(UList<T>&);
    friend std::ostream& operator << <T>(std::ostream&, const UList<T>&);

protected:
    std::vector<T> items;
};


template <class T>
UList<T>::UList(size_t size){
    std::vector<T> items(size);
}


template <class T>
bool UList<T>::find(const T& element){
    bool found=false;
    size_t index=0;
    while(index<items.size()){
        if(items.at(index)==element)
            found=true;
        index++;
    }
    return found;
}


template <class T>
size_t UList<T>::size() const{
    return items.size();
}


template <class T>
bool UList<T>::empty() const{
    return items.empty();
}

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const UList<T>& List){
    if(List.items.empty())
        out<<"list is empty."<<std::endl;
    else{
        for(size_t index=0;index<List.items.size();index++){
            out<<List.items.at(index);
                if(index<List.items.size()-1)
                    out<<" ";
        }
    }
    return out;
}


#endif
```

**sortBS.h**

```
#ifndef PROJ_SORTBS_H
#define PROJ_SORTBS_H
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include "UList.h"

template <class T>
void sort(UList<T>& List){
    std::vector<T>& items=List.items;
    size_t len=items.size();
    bool swapped = true;

    while((len--!=0)&& swapped){
        swapped=false;
        for(size_t i=0; i<len;++i){
            if(items[i+1]<items[i]){
                std::swap(items[i+1], items[i]);
                swapped=true;
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _What_ errors? The friend declarations should be sufficient, but they will restrict lookup of those functions to ADL, which may cause you problems in code that we can't see. You can (IIRC) later redeclare, _after_ `UList`, to get around that. I can only guess though because there is no concrete question here.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes forward declarations are necessary. You can make do with just the forward declaration of `UList` if you put `operator<<` and `sort` above the definition of `UList`. I'm not sure why `sort` is in a different header file anyway. If you wish to keep your code organized the way it is, the forward declarations are necessary.

Comment: sort is in a differnt header file because we are creating multiple header files for different sort functions, and I don't mean to be rude but my professor thinks otherwise. He told me they weren't neccessary and to fix it, but won't tell me how.

Comment: Not rude at all. Maybe he's right in this case. (Although if he's suggesting they are never needed, I don't believe that's true.) Hopefully someone else (or you!) will come up with a solution and post it. :)

Comment: my professor has no forward declarations and his declarations for `sort` and `operator <<` are both inside the `UList` class

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. I guarantee that your prof does *not* know more about C++ than the people here, and yet nobody has answered your question. I'm not sure what you mean by saying they are "both [declared] inside the UList class". Are they friend functions or not?

Comment: And I should add that compilers can differ. Is your prof using the same compiler as you?